# Some images now showing in iOS despite showing in Android

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a React Native app that pulls image urls from Amazon. I store the urls in a database, and reference them later as the source of my images.

After building up a good amount of entries in the database from several users, and releasing my app on Android, I decided to set my focus on iPhone. I'm now noticing that some images are not showing. So I go in and make sure that the urls are correct, and they are. Plus they're still working on the Android app just fine.

I then open Safari on my mac and plug the url into my browser. Same thing, it doesn't show up (Must be an Apple thing). An image such as this one...

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OAg8ggg8L._AC_SY400_FMwebp_.jpg

Will not show up... but an image such as this... with a similar url will...

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51sEOLVrs5L._AC_SY400_ML2_.jpg

I'm essentially getting a view like this on my app...
[image]

I just know this has something to do with my lack of understanding on how images now work in iOS, I've found that much through Google. I just don't know what. Can someone please explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI: when I try to open the top link on my Mac it says im attempting to download something (I declined), the second one opes to a picture as expected.

Comment: Yes, it tries to do the same thing for me. If you try from an Android or PC it opens just fine.

Comment: well your first and second links opened just fine for me , im on Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: I'm on Catalina 10.15.1... So I wonder if it's something they changed with Catalina. Also, I'm running an iPhone simulator. I wonder if it'd work on a physical device. Wish I had one right now :P

Comment: I downgraded to Mojave and still have the same issue.

Comment: out of curiosity, do the urls for the remaining images come without http(s)?

Comment: @kenmistry No, they all have https.

Comment: I wonder if I just need to resort to a base64 method.